# Add up numbers from tables for each month of the current year

Tags: php, mysql

I am wondering the best way to add up some figures for each month of the year so far and then print the information.

My table currently looks like this
Table name: payouts

Columns are date | paid

I then want it to add all the numbers up in the paid column for each month and print like this

```
January : 100,000
February : 2,300
```

e.t.c

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something with sum and grouping by the month.

```
select month, sum(amount) from `data_values` group by month
```

See it in action http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bd27/2

```
create table `data_values` (month varchar(50), amount decimal(18,2));
insert into `data_values` (month, amount) values ('January', 100),
('January', 50),
('Februari', 100),
('March', 100),
('April', 100),
('May', 100),
('May', 50),
('May', 25);
select month, sum(amount) from `data_values` group by month

month     sum(amount)
April     100
Februari  100
January   150
March     100
May       175
```

Now if you have an actual date field in your table you can use `monthname()` to get the grouping you want

See it in action http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09a1d6/1

```
create table `data_values` (buy_date date, amount decimal(18,2));
insert into `data_values` (buy_date, amount) values ('2008-01-01', 100),
('2008-01-14', 50),
('2008-02-15', 100),
('2008-03-01', 100),
('2008-04-01', 100),
('2008-05-02', 100),
('2008-05-10', 50),
('2008-05-22', 25);
select monthname(buy_date), sum(amount) from `data_values` group by monthname(buy_date)

monthname(buy_date) sum(amount)
April               100
February            100
January             150
March               100
May                 175
```

*You might want to add an extra group by clause `year(pay_date)` so it doesn't mix the years together. Unless that's what you want. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9acc82/2 `select year(buy_date), monthname(buy_date), sum(amount) from data_values group by year(buy_date), monthname(buy_date)`*

Comment: you know `DISTINCT` isn't a function?

Comment: Yea, was in my head too busy with switching from sql server syntax for these functions. thanks for the correction.

Comment: "Yea, was in my head too busy with switching from sql server syntax for these functions" `DISTINCT` in SQL server is also not a function i guess you need to drink some coffee

Comment: I usually use `max()` in sql server because it's the most hassle free one that sql server reminds me off via messages. And I just got a fresh cup.

Comment: `distinct` can be removed also by the way.. `group by` already returns distinct values.

Comment: Ah yes, again, working too much with sql server where you can't easily do that without getting a slap on your fingers. Corrected it. Thanks again :-)

Comment: Using the second method, is there a way to still display the months even if they are not in the database for example no amount is set for a month in april, so is there away to still display : april : 0

Comment: The most efficient way is to do that in php. You'd better ask that in a seperate question, where you ideally also provide a sample data set in JSON so it's easier to replicate and answer. But do demonstrate what you did yourself, or attemted yourself first. Otherwise that new question will get closed rapidly.

Comment: You could do it in a way like this, https://ideone.com/pdYOun @ScottyBoy